# How to define minimum and maximum font size to be scanned in tesseract

Tags: c#, tesseract

Is there any option to define font size or font height/width in tesseract? I have an image with some text that I want to OCR, but there is a smaller word just below it, almost touching it that I want to ignore.

E.g:

[image]

I tried to crop it, but then in some image the actual useful words get cut due to product movement.